# PHP защита ajax от инъекции

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

я реализую чат и сейчас сообщения отправляются методом ajax и уже на сервере встраиваются в бд напрямую, подскажите как можно обезопасить данный способ, чтобы нельзя было внедрить код. Если запретить какие-то символы, то какие будут лучше?

Comment: вот такая есть штука на php htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'])

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php и https://www.programulin.ru/zashchita-ot-xss-v-php

Comment: Спасибо, помогло